# Register page not working after removing php extension using .htaccess [FIXED]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So as the title says my register page is not working anymore since i removed .php extension, so here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

And i know that the .htaccess is the reason of this because i have tried to create account without the htaccess and it worked

One more thing to make things clear when i click submit button it just refreshes the page and the details are not inserted into the database

It turns out it was just some left gcaptcha checkup that i didnt needed anymore

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please post samples of links like FROM which link TO which link you want to redirect OR rewrite, thank you.

Comment: Also please take a look into your http server's error log file for errors raised by that implementation.

Comment: The reason for your issue most likely is that some other rewriting rule somewhere does not get applied any more. We cannot say anything about that though, since only you know your setup, we don't.